# how can i generate eip712 signature without using metamask?

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, signature

I need to create **multiple eip712 signatures**, which are not possible to create manually by accepting the metamask popups one by one.

Is there an alternative way of generating these signatures programatically?

Presently i am using the [_signTypedData method of Signer object](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTypedData) in ethers.js

I tried using `eth_signTypedData JSON RPC` while following the [EIP712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712#specification-of-the-eth_signtypeddata-json-rpc) on a infura node

```bash
curl -X POST --url https://celo-mainnet.infura.io/v3/895c273d61f4446f99b38bf444fc19f8 --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_signTypedData","params":["0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826", {"types":{"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"version","type":"string"},{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}],"Person":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"wallet","type":"address"}],"Mail":[{"name":"from","type":"Person"},{"name":"to","type":"Person"},{"name":"contents","type":"string"}]},"primaryType":"Mail","domain":{"name":"Ether Mail","version":"1","chainId":1,"verifyingContract":"0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC"},"message":{"from":{"name":"Cow","wallet":"0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826"},"to":{"name":"Bob","wallet":"0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB"},"contents":"Hello, Bob!"}}],"id":1}'
```

but it seems it does not support the use of the eth_signTypedData method.

The following error is displayed on firing the above query:

```js
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"method 'eth_signTypedData' not found"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! i got the solution...
So what i figured in the way was

1. The infura, Moralis or any external node incase do not provides the `eth_signTypedData` method which is expected because it needs a signer
2. Even running a [geth client](https://geth.ethereum.org/) do not provides with the `eth_signTypedData` method

I used the metamask's `eth-sig-util` package, which generates the signatures using the private key of the user.

```js
const {
  signTypedData,
  SignTypedDataVersion,
} = require("@metamask/eth-sig-util");

const domain = {
  name: "REIGNLABS", // contract deploy name
  version: "1", // contract deploy version
  chainId: 5, // env chain id
  verifyingContract: "0x23234234234...",
};

const types = {
  Struct: [
    { name: "id", type: "uint256" },
    { name: "_type", type: "uint256" },
    { name: "_address", type: "address" },
    { name: "_userAddresses", type: "string[]" },
  ],
  EIP712Domain: [
    { name: "name", type: "string" },
    { name: "version", type: "string" },
    { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
    { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
  ],
};

const privateKey =
  "zassda21332453asdasd...";// your private key

const obj = {
  id: 1,
  _type: 0,
  _address: "0xsdfdgerfsd...",
  _userAddresses: [
    "0xasdad23asda...",
    "0xjsdasdasdas...",
  ],
};

const signature = signTypedData({
  privateKey,
  data: {
    types,
    primaryType: "Struct",
    domain,
    message: obj,
  },
  version: SignTypedDataVersion.V4,
});

console.log(signature);
```